# Display cellular signal strength in decibels?

Tags: lumia, 8.1, signal

I'm trying to find the cellular signal strength my phone is experiencing in decibels (and ***not*** bars). The phone is a Nokia 635.

I'm poking around in *System*, but I don't see anything that might provide the value. The closest was *About*, but it only provided Model, Carrier, Firmware, etc. The second closest, *Cellular + SIM*, does not provide any technical information.

Where does Windows Phone 8.1 provide the signal strength in decibels?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I'm sorry, bars is the only "unit" there is on Windows Phone. This issue can't be fixed through an app either as I don't think developers have access to the necessary APIs.

Comment: Thanks Thomas. That really sucks. I'm trying to survey my house to determine the best location and direction for a cellular repeater to boost the signal. And I'm well aware of the games handset manufacturers play with bars. I can't make or receive calls with 1 or 2 bars at times...

Comment: If it's any consolation, I've been able to send/receive SMS messages with no bars (but not "no signal")

Answer (score 2):

Entering the code ##3282# in the phone dialer seems to work on phones with Windows 10 mobile (Lumia 950XL DS).  Just type in the code, and the phone enters Field Test mode (automatically, no need to hit the Call button).  First, it will warn you not to mess with any settings, at risk of losing your connectivity.  Then, select Net Monitor, and click on the icon next to Active Network, and scroll down the list for signal strengths.

Answer (score 1):

It depends on the phone make and model, most Nokia Lumia phones have the same process as iPhones, and can enter into field test mode by dialing a special code.

For Nokia Lumia try dialing

```
##3282#
```

[image: Nokia Lumia Field Test]

Comment: This doesn't work on my Lumia 930 with WP8. Here a quick overview of all Codes http://forum.xda-developers.com/showthread.php?t=2311626